# How to upload multiple images but with same last_id?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert multiple images  with the same last_id 
But I am having a problem the code does not do exactly what am looking for 
I have two tables one is user table and the image’s table so I want each user when he or she uploads images they should grab the last ids and use them in  image’s table but also each image will  be having a unique image Id . in the user table there user_id as primary key and in the image table there is user_id as a fk and image_d pk . bellow is my code .

```
<?php
$target = 'image_uploads/';
  if(isset($_FILES['image_name'])===true){
  $files = $_FILES['image_name'];
  for($x = 0 ; $x < count($files['name']); $x++){
  $name = $files['name'][$x] ;
  $temp_name = $files['tmp_name'][$x];
  #extention filter it takes only the extension  want 
$allowed ='gif,png,jpg,pdf';
$extension_allowed= explode(',',$allowed );  
$file_extention = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if(array_search($file_extention,$extension_allowed)){
}else {
echo 'We only allow gif, png ,jpg';
  exit();
} #extention  filter ends here 
  #check the size of the image 
  $file_size = $files['size'][$x];
  if($file_size > 2097152){
  echo 'The file should be lesS than 2MB';
  exit();
  }
    #check the size of the image  ends here
  #Rename images 
  $sub = substr(md5(rand()),0,7);
  #the above generates char and numbesr 
  $rand = rand(0,100000);
  $rename = $rand.$sub.$name;
  #Rename images ends here
  $move = move_uploaded_file($temp_name,$target.$rename); 
 #code to deal with the picture uploads ends here 
 }}
?>
<?php
try{
$query="INSERT INTO tish_user(username,Password,Previllage,date_created)
VALUES(:username,:Password,:Previllage,:date_created)";
$insert = $con->prepare($query);
$insert->execute(array(
':username'=>$user,
':Password'=>$Password,
':Previllage'=>$Previllage,
':date_created'=>$date_created));
#end of first table
################################################
#You select the first Id and put it in a variable then 
$id_last = ("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()");
$result =$con->prepare($id_last);
$result->execute();
$last_id = $result->fetchColumn();
############################## Last Id query Ends here
#insert into  clientinfo table 
$clientinfor="INSERT INTO tish_clientinfo
(title, firstname, lastname, nickname, idnumber, client_code, 
 company, country, city, province, address, cell, 
tel, webaddress, satifiedstatus, email, job_approval, cash_with_vat, 
cash_paid, date_registered,user_id)
VALUES(:title,:firstname,:lastname,:nickname,:idnumber,:client_code,
:company,:country,:city,:province,:address,
:cell,:tel,:webaddress,:satifiedstatus, :email, :job_approval,
:cash_with_vat,:cash_paid, :date_registered,$last_id)";
$clientinfor_insert = $con->prepare($clientinfor);
$clientinfor_insert->execute(array(
':title'=>$title,
':firstname'=>$firstname,
':lastname'=>$lastname,
':nickname'=>$nickname,
':idnumber'=>$idnumber,
':client_code'=>$client_code,
':company'=>$company,
':country'=>$country,
':city'=>$city,
':province'=>$province,
':address'=>$address,
':cell'=>$cell,
':tel'=>$tel,
':webaddress'=>$webaddress,
':satifiedstatus'=>$satifiedstatus,
':email'=>$email,
':job_approval'=>$job_approval,
':cash_with_vat'=>$cash_with_vat,
':cash_paid'=>$cash_paid,
':date_registered'=>$date_registered
));
#end of clien infor 
################################################
$security="INSERT INTO tish_security(ip_address,user_id)
VALUES(:ip_address,$last_id)";
$security_insert = $con->prepare($security);
$security_insert->execute(array(
':ip_address'=>$ip_address));
##########################end of security 
############ images 
$images ="INSERT INTO tish_images(user_id,image_name,date_registered)
VALUES($last_id,:image_name,:date_registered)";
$images_insert = $con->prepare($images);
$images_insert->execute(array(
':image_name'=>$rename,
':date_registered'=>$date_created));

##############################category 
$cats = $vals = array();
foreach ((array) $_POST['category_name'] as $cat) {
    if ('' !== ($cat = trim($cat))) {
        $cats[] = $cat;
        $vals[] = "({$last_id}, ?)";
    }
}
################################################
$sql = 'INSERT INTO tish_catigory (user_id, category_name) VALUES'. join(',', $vals);
$sth = $con->prepare($sql);
foreach ($cats as $i => $cat) {
    $sth->bindValue($i+1, $cat, PDO::PARAM_STR);
}
$sth->execute();

}catch(PDOException $e){
echo $e->getMessage();
}


var_dump($last_id);


?>
```

Comment: So what's not working, what error do you get?

Comment: Thanks Java West west answered it and its working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work I tested it and it worked

```
<?php
try{
$query="INSERT INTO tish_user(username,Password,Previllage,date_created)
VALUES(:username,:Password,:Previllage,:date_created)";
$insert = $con->prepare($query);
$insert->execute(array(
':username'=>$user,
':Password'=>$Password,
':Previllage'=>$Previllage,
':date_created'=>$date_created));
#end of first table
################################################
#You select the first Id and put it in a variable then 
$id_last = ("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()");
$result =$con->prepare($id_last);
$result->execute();
$last_id = $result->fetchColumn();
############################## Last Id query Ends here
#insert into  clientinfo table 
$clientinfor="INSERT INTO tish_clientinfo
(title, firstname, lastname, nickname, idnumber, client_code, 
 company, country, city, province, address, cell, 
tel, webaddress, satifiedstatus, email, job_approval, cash_with_vat, 
cash_paid, date_registered,user_id)
VALUES(:title,:firstname,:lastname,:nickname,:idnumber,:client_code,
:company,:country,:city,:province,:address,
:cell,:tel,:webaddress,:satifiedstatus, :email, :job_approval,
:cash_with_vat,:cash_paid, :date_registered,$last_id)";
$clientinfor_insert = $con->prepare($clientinfor);
$clientinfor_insert->execute(array(
':title'=>$title,
':firstname'=>$firstname,
':lastname'=>$lastname,
':nickname'=>$nickname,
':idnumber'=>$idnumber,
':client_code'=>$client_code,
':company'=>$company,
':country'=>$country,
':city'=>$city,
':province'=>$province,
':address'=>$address,
':cell'=>$cell,
':tel'=>$tel,
':webaddress'=>$webaddress,
':satifiedstatus'=>$satifiedstatus,
':email'=>$email,
':job_approval'=>$job_approval,
':cash_with_vat'=>$cash_with_vat,
':cash_paid'=>$cash_paid,
':date_registered'=>$date_registered
));
#end of clien infor 
################################################
$security="INSERT INTO tish_security(ip_address,user_id)
VALUES(:ip_address,$last_id)";
$security_insert = $con->prepare($security);
$security_insert->execute(array(
':ip_address'=>$ip_address));
##########################end of security 
############ images 
#code to deal with the picture uploads 
#target folder 
$target = 'image_uploads/';
  if(isset($_FILES['image_name'])===true){
  $files = $_FILES['image_name'];
  for($x = 0 ; $x < count($files['name']); $x++){
  $name = $files['name'][$x] ;
  $temp_name = $files['tmp_name'][$x];
  #extention filter it takes only the extension  want 
$allowed ='gif,png,jpg,pdf';
$extension_allowed= explode(',',$allowed );  
$file_extention = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if(array_search($file_extention,$extension_allowed)){
}else {
echo 'We only allow gif, png ,jpg';
  exit();
} #extention  filter ends here 
  #check the size of the image 
  $file_size = $files['size'][$x];
  if($file_size > 2097152){
  echo 'The file should be lesS than 2MB';
  exit();
  }
    #check the size of the image  ends here
  #Rename images 
  $sub = substr(md5(rand()),0,7);
  #the above generates char and numbesr 
  $rand = rand(0,100000);
  $rename = $rand.$sub.$name;
  #Rename images ends here
  $move = move_uploaded_file($temp_name,$target.$rename); 
 #code to deal with the picture uploads ends here 


$images ="INSERT INTO tish_images(user_id,image_name,date_registered)
VALUES($last_id,:image_name,:date_registered)";
$images_insert = $con->prepare($images);
$images_insert->execute(array(
':image_name'=>$rename,
':date_registered'=>$date_created));
}}
##############################category 
$cats = $vals = array();
foreach ((array) $_POST['category_name'] as $cat) {
    if ('' !== ($cat = trim($cat))) {
        $cats[] = $cat;
        $vals[] = "({$last_id}, ?)";
    }
}
################################################
$sql = 'INSERT INTO tish_catigory (user_id, category_name) VALUES'. join(',', $vals);
$sth = $con->prepare($sql);
foreach ($cats as $i => $cat) {
    $sth->bindValue($i+1, $cat, PDO::PARAM_STR);
}
$sth->execute();


############# property table##########################################################
/*$property ="INSERT INTO tish_propertyinfo(user_id,date_registered)
VALUES($last_id,:date_registered)";
$property_insert = $con->prepare($images);
$property_insert->execute(array(':date_registered'=>$date_created));
*/}catch(PDOException $e){
echo $e->getMessage();
}
#for the insert check boxes 

var_dump($last_id);
#images 

?>
```